# Webpack ProvidePlugin vs externals?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, amd, webpack

I'm exploring the idea of using [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) with [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/).

I've followed the quick start guide and has a general idea of how Webpack works, but I'm unclear on how to load dependency library like jquery / backbone / underscore.

Should they be loaded externally with `<script>` or is this something Webpack can handle like RequireJS's shim?

According to the [webpack doc: shimming modules](http://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html), `ProvidePlugin` and `externals` seem to be related to this (so is `bundle!` loader somewhere) but I cannot figure out when to use which.

Thanks

Answer (score 162, accepted):

It's both possible: You can include libraries with a `<script>` (i. e. to use a library from a CDN) or include them into the generated bundle.

If you load it via `<script>` tag, you can use the `externals` option to allow to write `require(...)` in your modules.

Example with library from CDN:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.min.js"></script>

// the artifial module "jquery" exports the global var "jQuery"
externals: { jquery: "jQuery" }

// inside any module
var $ = require("jquery");
```

Example with library included in bundle:

```
copy `jquery-git2.min.js` to your local filesystem

// make "jquery" resolve to your local copy of the library
// i. e. through the resolve.alias option
resolve: { alias: { jquery: "/path/to/jquery-git2.min.js" } }

// inside any module
var $ = require("jquery");
```

---

The `ProvidePlugin` can map modules to (free) variables. So you could define: "Every time I use the (free) variable `xyz` inside a module you (webpack) should set `xyz` to `require("abc")`."

Example without `ProvidePlugin`:

```
// You need to require underscore before you can use it
var _ = require("underscore");
_.size(...);
```

Example with `ProvidePlugin`:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    "_": "underscore"
  }) 
]

// If you use "_", underscore is automatically required
_.size(...)
```

---

Summary:

- Library from CDN: Use `<script>` tag and `externals` option
- Library from filesystem: Include the library in the bundle.
  (Maybe modify `resolve` options to find the library)
- `externals`: Make global vars available as module
- `ProvidePlugin`: Make modules available as free variables inside modules

Comment: Should add `new` before `webpack.ProvidePlugin`

http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html

Comment: Why not just use the script-loader? This is much easier, like @dtothefp did explained

Comment: If my webpack.config file is in a folder called javascript and inside that I have a folder called vendor with my jquery file. should the path not be. resolve: { alias: { jquery: "vendor/jquery-1.10.2.js" } }. Still doesn't work for me using the alias

Comment: Just pass an absolute path to the alias option. If you pass a relative path it's relative to the location of the require/import in webpack 1. In webpack 2 it's relative to the webpack.config.js file resp. the context option.

Comment: @TobiasK. An absolute path doesn't cooperate with default exports. I'm getting an object `{__esModule: true, default: MY_DEFAULT_EXPORT}` instead of `MY_DEFAULT_EXPORT` in the files.

Answer (score 26):

Something cool to note is that if you use the `ProvidePlugin` in combination with the `externals` property it will allow you to have `jQuery` passed into your webpack module closure without having to explicitly `require` it. This can be useful for refactoring legacy code with a lot of different files referencing `$`.

```
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: { 
    filename: '[name].js' 
  },
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
    })
  ]
};
```

now in index.js

```
console.log(typeof $ === 'function');
```

will have a compiled output with something like below passed into the `webpackBootstrap` closure:

```
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    /* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function($) {
        console.log(typeof $ === 'function');

    /* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(exports, __webpack_require__(1)))

/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    module.exports = jQuery;

/***/ }
/******/ ])
```

Therefore, you can see that `$` is referencing the global/window `jQuery` from the CDN, but is being passed into the closure. I'm not sure if this is intended functionality or a lucky hack but it seems to work well for my use case.

Comment: you didn't need either plugin if you weren't going to `require/import` it. `$` would just work because it will reach up to the global scope no matter what. The `ProviderPlugin` requires parsing the AST so it's an expensive plugin and will add to your build time noticeably. So it's basically a waste.

Comment: @dtohefp this answer is a godsend. Can you possibly explain why `ProvidePlugin` returned an object like, `myModule.default` unless I added the module to externals? I never knew there would be any direct relationship.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old post but thought it would be useful to mention that the webpack script loader may be useful in this case as well.  From the webpack docs:

"script: Executes a JavaScript file once in global context (like in script tag), requires are not parsed."

http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html

https://github.com/webpack/script-loader

I have found this particularly useful when migrating older build processes that concat JS vendor files and app files together.  A word of warning is that the script loader seems only to work through overloading `require()` and doesn't work as far as I can tell by being specified within a webpack.config file.  Although, many argue that overloading `require` is bad practice, it can be quite useful for concating vendor and app script in one bundle, and at the same time exposing JS Globals that don't have to be shimmed into addition webpack bundles.  For example:

```
require('script!jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie');
require('script!history.js/scripts/bundled-uncompressed/html4+html5/jquery.history');
require('script!momentjs');

require('./scripts/main.js');
```

This would make $.cookie, History, and moment globally available inside and outside of this bundle, and bundle these vendor libs with the main.js script and all it's `require`d files.

Also, useful with this technique is:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ["", ".js"],
  modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components']
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
   )
]
```

which is using Bower, will look at the `main` file in each `require`d libraries package.json.  In the above example, History.js doesn't have a `main` file specified, so the path to the file is necessary.