# Webpack and External Libs: ProvidePlugin vs entry vs global import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

## 1. `ProvidePlugin()`

Looks like a commonly used approach. There is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Couto/b29676dd1ab8714a818f) about it, showcasing how to include **whatwg-fetch** polyfill into a Webpack build. Lots of answers on StackOverflow use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39149318/274117) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23374129/274117).

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  '$': 'jquery',
  'jQuery': 'jquery',
  'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
})
```

#### Pros

- It works. (please update this list if I am missing something)

#### Cons

- Need to keep track of global libraries in the Webpack config.

## 2. `entry: [...]`

I was a little surprised by this approach when I discovered it in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Couto/b29676dd1ab8714a818f#gistcomment-1782021) but it works just as well.

```
entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    'whatwg-fetch',
    'jquery',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/app.js')
],
```

#### Pros

- It works.
- I can drop `ProvidePlugin()` entirely.

#### Cons

- Need to keep track of global libraries in the Webpack config.

## 3. Top-level `import`

This one is very straightforward, see this [app.js](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/app.js#L9) example. This file is an entry-point to a React application.

```
/**
 * app.js
 */

import 'whatwg-fetch';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import 'jquery';
```

#### Pros

- It works just as well.
- Easy add/remove. No need to touch the Webpack config.

#### Cons

- Doesn't look like this approach alone will work with jQuery plugins, e.g. *bootstrap.js*.

**Observation**: Between all three approaches, I haven't noticed any changes in the bundle size.

Is there one recommended way of handling global libraries with Webpack (and React)? Would any of these solutions cause a problem down the road with server-side rendering?

Thanks!

Comment: `entry` isn't a good idea at all if you have multiple entry points.

Answer (score 25):

I wouldn't recommend exposing libraries as global unless you really do need it, i.e. the point of a module system is to explicitly declare dependencies, e.g.

```
// app.js
import $ from 'jquery';
$.ajax(...);
```

If you absolutely do need jQuery on the global because a third party script requires it on your page or maybe for debugging in the console then here's some information regarding the approaches you've listed:

ProvidePlugin

The ProvidePlugin won't expose jQuery on the global and is really designed to fix third-party modules which incorrectly rely on the presence of a global module so I wouldn't recommend this, e.g.

```
// app.js
$.ajax(...);
```

Is effectively transpiled into:

```
// app.js
require('jquery').ajax(...);
```

Entry & Top level import

These approaches won't work for a regular UMD module such as jQuery as jQuery is smart enough not to expose itself on the global when being loaded by a commonjs / amd / es6 aware loader.

These two approaches are however ideal for modules with side effects such as the `babel-polyfill` / `whatwg-fetch` because they don't export anything, they inherently mutate the global environment.

---

My recommendation for jQuery is therefore to use the [`expose-loader`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#expose-loader) which is designed to expose a modules export globally, e.g.

```
// webpack.config.js
{
    module: {
        loaders: [
            test: require.resolve('jquery'),
            loader: 'expose-loader?jQuery!expose-loader?$'
        ]
    }
}
```

You then still need to import it in your app code:

```
// app.js
import $ from 'jquery';
$.ajax(...)
```

But it's available on the global for other scripts on the page to access if absolutely necessary:

```
// console
window.$
window.jQuery
```

NOTE: Technically you could just `import 'jquery'` once in your entry point when using the expose loader and then rely on the global in other modules.

As I say however, it isn't really advisable to expose a module if you don't need to, even if you happen to currently use it in every other module.

Answer (score 0):

Just find out that provided lib will be overwritten, if you include several packs (entry points) in one page when you use ProvidePlugin. Examples are for RoR and Webpacker, but i assume it doesn't matter.

For example you have in your layout:

```
  javascript_pack_tag 'application',
                      'metronic'
```

And in configs you have:

```
  environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
      "window.$": "jquery",
      _: 'underscore',
      Handlebars: 'handlebars'
  }));
```

If in `application.js` you require libraries, which mutate JQuery, you will loose all this mutation in `metronic.js` and in browser, even if you expose JQuery with expose-loader.

Correct me if i am wrong, probably ProvidePlugin just imports libs in each entry point.