# angular.module undefined when using webpack

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

Angular 1.5.8, Webpack 2.1.0-beta.25

I'm getting an error that angular is undefined when I try to use it with webpack.  I've tried to load angular as an external and as part of the package as detailed here: [Webpack ProvidePlugin vs externals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305599/webpack-provideplugin-vs-externals)

I've added this code at my entry point to test:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
// import angular from 'angular'; <!-- have tried this too

angular.module('test', []);
```

I can hold my mouse over the line of code in the debugger and it seems to be able to find angular.  Yet once I hit F10 I get the error.

[image]

[image]

My webpack.common.config:

```
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery',
        window: 'window',
        angular: 'angular'
    },

      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: 'jquery',
          angular: 'angular',
          _: 'lodash',
          moment: 'moment'
      }),
```

Index.html (when providing externally):

```
<body id="bootstrap-overrides">

    <sb-app></sb-app>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slideout/0.1.11/slideout.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sbMain.bundle.js"></script>

</body>
```

sbMain.bundle.js is where the error is occuring, even though it's loaded last (angular is first)

Comment: What about the order in which each script is included?

Comment: I added my index.html to the question.  Angular is loaded before my bundled files.

Comment: AFAICT, you should not be using `externals` + `ProviderPlugin` + `import`. Either use `externals` + `ProviderPlugin` *or* `externals` + `import`.

Comment: yea, I've tried it both ways, same error

Comment: This is strange. (Then again, my webpack-fu is rather weak.) Would it be possible to create a minimal reproduction (e.g. a repo)?

Comment: I think somewhere in my bundling I'm overwriting global angular with a blank object somehow.

Comment: @RyanLangton have you found any resolutions to your problem?